# r programming - logistic regression plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression

```
  mutate(prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 0","1"))%>%
>   ggplot(aes( plasma_glucose, prob)) +
+   geom_point(alpha = 1) +
+   geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial")) +
+   labs(
+     title = "Logistic Regression Model", 
+     x = "Plasma Glucose Concentration",
+     y = "Probability of being diabete-pos"
+   )
```

output-
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `prob`.
i `prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 0, 1, )`.
x unused argument (alist())

I am new to R programming and not sure how to rectify the above code? I am trying to plot logistic regression result.

Comment: Try ifelse(outcome == "pos", 0,1)

Comment: tried that! but not working

Comment: remove %>% after  mutate(prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 0,1))%>%

Comment: new error - Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `prob`.
i `prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 1, 0, )`.
x unused argument (alist())

Comment: prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 1, 0, ) delete , (comma)

Comment: Tried removing the comma - New error - Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: Your mutate is not on the right hand side of a pipe, so your derivation of prob is the first argument. That’s not a data frame. Hence the  latest error.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn`t get what you saying. could you please elaborate. I am new to R and a Dentist. Trying to learn R prog for research analysis. So not too familiar with technicalities. sorry.

Comment: you need to pass the dataframe to the mutate function, for example if your dataframe is da , `da %>% mutate(prob = ifelse(outcome == "pos", 0","1"))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer regarding your first error message `unused argument (alist())`, in case anybody else gets here by googling that error message:

- You get the `unused argument` error in R if you try to call a function with an argument this function doesn't have: such as:

```r
foo <- function(x) x

foo(x = 10, y = 10) # notice the y-argument
#> Error in foo(x = 10, y = 10): unused argument (y = 10)
```

- You get the `unused argument (alist())` error if you call a function with a trailing comma, as R see this as another - completely empty - argument. For example:

```r
foo(x = 10, ) # notice the comma
#> Error in foo(x = 10, ): unused argument (alist())
```

As @Rfanatic said in the comments, remove the extra comma and this error message goes away.